# webmin's bind & nameserver - NS doesn't resolve

Tags: bind, nameserver

Got a problem setting up a nameserver. Here are the details:

domain http://stagingtestserver.com.au/
(I did some updates and now www.stagingtestserver.com.au won't resolve)

I got some errors in www.intodns.com/stagingtestserver.com.au as well. I could not ping ns1. and ns2. also.

This is the record file under /var/named/stagingtestserver.com.au.hosts:

> ```
> $ttl 38400
> stagingtestserver.com.au. IN  SOA ns1.stagingtestserver.com.au myemail\.here.gmail.com. (
>           1341370630
>           10800
>           3600
>           604800
>           38400 )
> stagingtestserver.com.au. IN  A   202.4.229.161
> www.stagingtestserver.com.au. IN  A   202.4.229.161
> ftp.stagingtestserver.com.au. IN  A   202.4.229.161
> m.stagingtestserver.com.au.   IN  A   202.4.229.161
> localhost.stagingtestserver.com.au.   IN  A   127.0.0.1
> webmail.stagingtestserver.com.au. IN  A   202.4.229.161
> admin.stagingtestserver.com.au.   IN  A   202.4.229.161
> mail.stagingtestserver.com.au.    IN  A   202.4.229.161
> stagingtestserver.com.au. IN  MX  5 mail.stagingtestserver.com.au.
> ns1.stagingtestserver.com.au. IN  A   202.4.229.161
> ns2.stagingtestserver.com.au. IN  A   202.4.229.172
> stagingtestserver.com.au. IN  NS  ns1.stagingtestserver.com.au.
> stagingtestserver.com.au. IN  NS  ns2.stagingtestserver.com.au.
> ```

Any thoughts, guys? Thanks and I appreciate all your thoughts/help/(ahem  violent) reactions? :)

Comment: Do you have glue records set up with your registrar?

Answer (score 1):

[Squish](http://www.squish.net/dnscheck/) says that the glue is setup correctly, but requests to your nameservers are all timing out.  I can ping them both, so that's OK, my best guess would be that you haven't cracked open the firewall.

Also, running both your nameserver IPs on the same machine is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Hmm, I also read in some forum that port 53 should be open. I added this port in the iptable rules and even stopped that service, but to no avail. Also, I was intrigued by the IPs on the same IP comment, so I'll revert back to the hosting's NS for now and will resume later with your comments in mind. Thanks!